# Multiple searchboxes via AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to use several textboxes on the page which all have their own search query to fetch data from the database.

I have it working on 1 textbox but I can't get it to work for 2 or more textboxes.

This is my code:

**php**

```
$opts = (isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : FALSE);  
$val = (isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : FALSE);
$val2 = (isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : FALSE);

    if ($val != null){
    $where = " WHERE boekingsnummer LIKE '".$val."%'";  
    }  
    if ($val2 != null){
    $where = " WHERE huiscode LIKE '".$val2."%'";  
    }  

$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
```

**ajax**

```
$('#boekingsnummer_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val());        
});

$('#huiscode_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val());        
});

function updateEmployeesText(val){        
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {text: val},
    success: function(records){
        $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
    }        
}); 
}
```

Comment: the `where like` doesn't work because it got overwritten. try `.=` then change it to `AND`. why are you comparing it to null. you explicitly written if not set to false

Comment: Could you give me an example please, sorry but im relatively new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

generate a string and pass it through url.

```
$('#huiscode_1').keyup(function(){ 
    var text = '?val1='+$(this).val()+'&val2='$('#boekingsnummer_1').val();
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val(text));        
});

function updateEmployeesText(val){        
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php"+val,
    cache: false,
    success: function(records){
        $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
    }        
}); 
}
```

like this. generate the string for every input fields u want and do the necessary checks before generating.GET the values on php script & process.hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you for your help but when I try this then the data from Ajax does not show on the screen anymore